# SharePoint Custom Field - is it possible to handle item deletion event?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, field, custom-fields, spfield

I'm expanding `SPFieldText` and `BaseFieldControl` to create a custom field. The field saves some data externally (for example, on a database or on another list)
Within the control I'm able to handle Edit and New events (using `ControlMode`).

I'd like to run a function and clean up some data when an *item* containing my field is deleted. Is this possible, in the context of a custom field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the field has no "knowledge" of the item it is contained in. You could however perform the cleanup by creating an ItemEventReceiver.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that'd be the case, but I wanted to avoid an event receiver. That's the only option I could think of too, to attach an receiver when I create the custom column. Makes my project even messier `:P` . You're right, though, I don't really have events for creating and editing the item, I only got a control on the page.